# Alternatives to the V35 interface

Tags: serial, cable, router

I am trying to find an alternative for the legacy cables I am using.

I currently have a Cisco router connected to a DL 600 E (Multiplexer).

On the Cisco router there is a serial port.

On the Multiplexer there is a D25 port.

At the moment there is a Serial/V35 cable running from the router and connected to a V35/D25 cable which is connected to the Multiplexer.

My questions, can I simply run a serial to D25 connection from the router to the multiplexer? Or does it have to be connected using V35s to work?

Thanks in advance, 
Kim

Comment: Also, my current multiplexer can only connect to an ethernet cable using a connector. Are there any multiplexers out there that have RJ45 cables and achieve the same result?